# How can I do image manipulation on a very large BMP?

Tags: java, image-processing, bitmap

I am trying to do some manipulation (specifically, conversion to a different type of splitting into tiles) on a set of very large (a few GB) BMP image files.

I'm not sure I understand the BMP file format, but is it necessary to load the entire file into memory? I was unable to find any API that didn't require loading the entire file at some point. ImageMagick wasn't able to do it either.

Java would be the best tool of choice for me, but any other solution including command line tools or desktop software would be acceptable.

Comment: Which transformations do you want to do? Some can be done with a shifting window, so you wouldn't need to load all. Others might allow streaming, and some might need it all:)

Comment: nothing serious, splitting into tiles, or converting to a more compressed format

Answer (score 2):

Based on [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format), it should be reasonably apparent that you can use the fact that it's row-packed.  You should be able to read part of a row, store it, advance to the same position in the next row and repeat until you have completed a tile of the desired size.  Obviously you may be able to do multiple tiles at once if you can store an entire row worth of tiles in memory all at once.

It is not necessary to load more than the header of the file at once.  The header format is describe in the linked Wikipedia entry.  It's probably worth paying attention to any compression schemes being used - compression is likely to make this task a bit harder (though still not impossible) :)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about 2011 year of this questing, but Java 7 (and possibly 6) has good approach for such pleasure.

Use ImageReader and ImageReadParam classes, they allow to read any rectangular part of source image if needed. Set source rectangle and read

```
... // initialization

private javax.imageio.ImageReadParam m_params;
private javax.imageio.ImageReader m_reader;

... // reading

m_params.setSourceRegion( readRect );
BufferedImage rdImg = m_reader.read( i, m_params );

... // processing/displaying etc
```

As BMP (it works too for any standard Java image type) is very planar format without any compression in 99.99% cases, to read any its part such way is very fast process with low memory consumption except resulted BufferedImage. Or you can even reuse previous BufferedImage on consequent request with the rect of same dimensions. See ImageReadParam.setDestination(BufferedImage destination). But I didn't test this option.

Also I found one small reading bug namely in BMP reader class implementation of Java runtime lib. If somebody be  interested in this, I'll show simple way to correct it.